# How can I reboot my Linux system every 60 seconds?

Tags: linux, busybox

I am debugging some embedded hardware that runs Linux 3.2.6 Angstrom distro, I need the unit to reboot every 60 seconds. I tried this:

```
In /etc/rc5.d : S99reboot -> /home/root/test.sh
/home/root/test.sh contains only this: /home/root/rebootunit.sh&
/home/root/rebootunit.sh has this:
echo "sleep 60 and reboot"
sleep 60
reboot
```

works fine from the command line, but when run from startup, the unit starts to shutdown, then gets stuck with this:

```
Deactivating swap...
Unmounting local filesystems...

Give root password for system maintenance
(or type Control-D for normal startup):
```

And the filesystem is in read-only mode. I'm not sure why this happened, or if there is another way to do this - I'm open to suggestions, thanks

Comment: Does it have to be 60 seconds after completing startup, or 60 seconds after the last reset?

Comment: Random guess: Fire it off as a background process `(sleep 60 && reboot) &` so your init script finishes. Maybe it's not happy that you tried to reboot before your script (and thus the boot) was done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put

```
* * * * * /sbin/reboot
```

in root's crontab.

Clarification: since cron doesn't run until the system is fully up, you don't get conflicts between startup and shutdown procedures.

Comment: Ok - finally got cron installed - but it's not working at startup, only if I restart it? I'm going to post as a separate question. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Append `shutdown -r 60` to `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: As far as I can tell /etc/rc.local is not getting called, only the things in /etc/rc5.d get called. Maybe something about this distro? Here's my attempt:         root@SL1000-1103DC:~# cd /etc
root@SL1000-1103DC:/etc# ls -l rc.local
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           23 Jun 16 13:47 rc.local
root@SL1000-1103DC:/etc# cat rc.local 
echo "Hello rc.local"

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to issue the reboot command only after the system is fully booted and all boot activities are complete.  Using rc.local is a good idea but the fact that it is a foreground command might still be a problem.  So backgrounding the command might also be a good idea.

shutdown -r 30 &

Or issue an at job (from rc.local) that does it outside the start-up scripts:

at -f /home/root/test.sh now

Answer (score 0):

```
[root@linux]crontab -e
```

Then append this line:

```
* * * * * /sbin/reboot
```

It will create new cron job that reboots your machine every minute.

**Good luck!**